# MySQL query fetch array not working

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I've some MySQL queries, but one of them isn't working ("Number 1"). The other query ("Number 2") works fine. But I must repeat "Number 2" many times, more than 100. It's hard. I don't get query "Number 1" to work. What's wrong?

"Number 1"

```
<?php
require_once ("../config/config.db.inc.php");

$sdd_db_host = DB_HOSTNAME;
$sdd_db_name = DB_DATABASE;
$sdd_db_user = DB_USERNAME;
$sdd_db_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);
mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);

mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
$menu = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * `tbl_customers`"));

echo $menu['finskaya_razdel']; ?>
```

Nothing happend, but it should! ['finskaya_razdel'] isn't only one...

"Number 2"

```
<?php
require_once ("../config/config.db.inc.php");

$sdd_db_host = DB_HOSTNAME;
$sdd_db_name = DB_DATABASE;
$sdd_db_user = DB_USERNAME;
$sdd_db_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);
mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);

mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");

$menu = mysql_query("SELECT finskaya_razdel FROM `tbl_customers` WHERE customers_id='1008' or customers_id='8'");
$menu_res = mysql_result($menu, 0);

echo $menu_res; ?>
```

This query works. But it's crazy... I've more than 100 queries to do. Number 1 more "gorgeous". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use mysqli or pdo. mysql is deprecated.

Comment: It would also be interesting what `print_r($menu);` would return

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez... thank you...

Comment: @chade_... Thank you... but print_r even hang a page))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `msql_fetch_*` extracts one row at a time. You have to loop and apply it every time.
2. To use column names you have to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` (with `mysql_fetch_array` you'd have to use index numbers).

So...

```
$menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu))
    echo $row["finskaya_razdel"];
```

... or if you need to have the results in a php multidimensional array...

```
$menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers");

$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu))
    $results[] = $row;
```

***NOTE***: @BarclickFloresVelasquez is right. You should move to mysqli or PDO

Comment: The `FROM` was missing in the query. Try now

Comment: And i don't need it in "while".. it' must be in different parts of some page)... Yeah i found FROM.. and it's happend; But could i do it without "while".

Comment: Then use the second option. Load the results in a php multidimensional array and use it where you want

Comment: WOW.. i even don't understand you... Please can you give me an example.

Comment: It's already in the answer. The second example. `$results` would be your array

Comment: when in "while" i do  echo $row["finskaya_razdel"]."|".$row["hello_razdel"]."|"; in result it's crazy: |||||| Finskaya|| Hello||| ||||||||||||

Comment: You're doing an `echo` for each row of your table. If that values are empty, you don't see anything, just the two '|' you've echo for every row

Comment: it's not so simple.. write more than 100 rows... Thank you very much for your time and experience